# C Why is the # of threads created in my code inconsistent?

Tags: c, multithreading

The goal of my assignment is to create a loop to spawn 5 threads with integer arguments 0 through 4. I have 3 files: thread_demo.c that contains the main function, worker.c that contains the function to compute square of the argument, and header.h to keep the 2 files together.

thread_demo.c

```
#include "header.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5
#define PROMPT_SIZE 5

int main(){
        pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
        pthread_attr_t pthread_attributes;

        int *prompt;
        scanf("%d", &prompt);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
                pthread_create(&threads[i], &pthread_attributes, &worker, (void *) prompt);
        } 
}
```

worker.c

```
#include "header.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void *worker(void * num){
        int *input;
        input = (int*) &num;

        // Calculate square
        int output = *input * *input;

        printf("The square of %d", *input);
        printf(" is %d.\n", output);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I have no compile errors, but the number of threads my code spawns is inconsistent. The pictures shown are my outputs from entering "5" 3 different times in which I have not made changes to the code. I'm not sure what causes this, I know I'm missing something but I don't know what it is. 
I also have to make "the main thread wait until all threads have completed",  which is confusing to me. When I spawn the 5 threads, how do I know which is the main thread? 
I've never wrote code related to processes and threads so I'm completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should start with making your code compile (remove `)` from `int *prompt);`) and avoiding to invoke undefined behavior (use proper type for reading data via `scanf()`).

Comment: Just a side note, the square root of 5 is *not* 25.

Comment: oh my bad that extra ")" got there when I was formatting my code on here somehow

Comment: You have: `int *prompt; scanf("%d", &prompt);` – you don't want the `*`.  At the moment, you pass the address of an uninitialized pointer to `scanf()` and ask it to read an integer into it.  You should be be getting shrieks from your compiler about the type mismatch — if you aren't, either turn up the compiler warnings so that such problems are identified as errors, or get a better compiler. It may sort of work if you are using a machine where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` — most 32-bit systems fit that bill, but most 64-bit systems do not. There are other consequential issues to resolve too.

Comment: Note that you pass the same value (`prompt`) to each thread; that's why each thread does the same job.

Comment: The "main thread" is the thread that called `main`. In the case of your code, it's the thread that created the other threads.

Comment: When you write code that creates threads then you also need to know what a threading race bug looks like.  That's what it looks like.  The answer you got only solves one of them, separate printf() statements are going to get their output mixed up.  Which is feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is probably exiting before all your threads are complete. This would explain why you see different outputs on different runs: sometimes your program exits more or less quickly allowing less or more of the work to complete.

You need to keep your program from exiting (returning from `main()`) until all your thread are finished. To do this, you can use `pthread_join` for each of the threads. Add after you create all the threads:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i]);
}
```

`ptread_join` will block (stop execution at that line) until the thread has terminated.

From the docs:

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread
>          to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
>          pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread
>          must be joinable.
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html